# Bloc listener not triggered

Tags: flutter, dart, listener, bloc

I have a login screen. When logo is clicked, I want display a loading on top of it. The loading widget I put in `ContainerWithLoadingOverlay`.

**main.dart**

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => sl<OverlayLoadingCubit>()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        localizationsDelegates: [
          EasyLocalization.of(context)!.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: EasyLocalization.of(context)!.supportedLocales,
        locale: EasyLocalization.of(context)!.locale,
        title: kAppTitle,
        theme: AppTheme.light,
        onGenerateRoute: AppRoute.onGenerateRoutes,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**log_in_screen.dart**

```
 return Scaffold(
        body: ContainerWithLoadingOverlay(    <--- this for loading 
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const AppLogo(
                      width: 150,
                      height: 150,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 32),
                    InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          context.read<LogInCubit>().signIn(
                              SignInParams(
                                  email: _emailController.text,
                                  password: _passwordController.text));
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "Welcome back.",
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                        )),
                    const SizedBox(height: 32),
                    // _loginForm(context, isShown),
                  ],
                ),
              ))),
    ));
  }
```

**log_in_cubit.dart**

```
class LogInCubit extends Cubit<LogInState> {
  final OverlayLoadingCubit _loadingCubit;
  final SignInUseCase _useCase;

  LogInCubit(this._useCase, this._loadingCubit) : super(LogInLoading());

  Future<void> signIn(SignInParams params) async {
    _loadingCubit.startLoading();  
           ...
  }
}
```

**overlay_loading_state.dart**

```
part of 'overlay_loading_cubit.dart';

abstract class OverlayLoadingState {
  const OverlayLoadingState();
}

class OverlayLoadingInitial extends OverlayLoadingState {}

class IsLoadingState extends OverlayLoadingState {}
```

**overlay_loading_cubit.dart**

```
class OverlayLoadingCubit extends Cubit<OverlayLoadingState> {
  OverlayLoadingCubit() : super(OverlayLoadingInitial());

   startLoading() {
    debugPrint("start loading");  <-- this line is able to print
    emit(IsLoadingState());  
    return;
  }
}
```

**container_with_loading_overlay.dart**

```
class ContainerWithLoadingOverlay extends HookWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ContainerWithLoadingOverlay({Key? key, required this.child})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<OverlayLoadingCubit, OverlayLoadingState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        debugPrint("call from listener");  <--- this line not calling
        if (state is OverlayLoadingInitial) {
          context.loaderOverlay.hide();
        }

        if (state is IsLoadingState) {
          context.loaderOverlay.show();
        }
      },
      child: LoaderOverlay(
        useDefaultLoading: false,
        overlayWidget: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I expect the bloc listener in class `ContainerWithLoadingOverlay` will get triggered and loading dialog will show, but it not triggred..what's the issue?

Comment: have you provided `OverlayLoadingCubit` to `ContainerWithLoadingOverlay`?

Comment: where to check whether I have provided? @Hamed

Comment: it should be provided in the upper widget tree, where did you provide this cubit to widget tree?

Comment: @Hamed post edited..you mean this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BlocListener is triggered only when it detects a state change. If your BlocListener is not being triggered, try emitting an OverlayLoadingInitial() state first, wait for a second, and then emit the isLoadingStates state.

Here's an example code:

```
void startLoading() {
  // debugPrint("start loading");  <-- this line is able to print
  emit(OverlayLoadingInitial());
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)); // Emulates your signIn request
  emit(IsLoadingState());
  return;
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, but not working..I have push complete code to git.
https://github.com/tony123S/sampleProject

Comment: I found the issue. This is happening because you registered the OverlayLoadingCubit dependency as a factory, so every time you call sl(), a new instance of OverlayLoadingCubit is created, which is different from the instance created in BlocProvider(create: (_) => sl<OverlayLoadingCubit>()). To solve this, inject the dependency as a singleton instead.

You can verify this by printing the hashcode of the OverlayLoadingCubit instance.

I will submit a PR to your project. Don't forget to upvote my answer if it helps you.
pr url: https://github.com/tony123S/sampleProject/pull/1

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by `DI`, instance of `overlayLoadingCubit` is not the same in different parts of the app, as you can use `Bloc` as a dependency injector no need to use `DI` in this case.

You can change `app.dart` like this:

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    OverlayLoadingCubit overlayLoadingCubit = OverlayLoadingCubit();
    LogInCubit logInCubit = LogInCubit(overlayLoadingCubit);

    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => overlayLoadingCubit),
        BlocProvider(create: (_) => logInCubit),
      ],
      child: const MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: "Sample",
        onGenerateRoute: AppRoute.onGenerateRoutes,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

in addition, no need to provide `OverlayLoadingCubit` in `app_route.dart`:

```dart
class AppRoute {
  static const loginScreen = '/loginPage';

  static MaterialPageRoute<dynamic> _loginScreenRoute() =>
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LogInScreen());

  static Route? onGenerateRoutes(RouteSettings settings) => _loginScreenRoute();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but `call from listener` still not printing.

Comment: @AI.please put your `OverlayLoadingState` class in your question.
I need to check it as well.

Comment: @AI. the answer has been updated, please test new one.

Comment: I have tried it, but not working..I have push complete code to git. github.com/tony123S/sampleProject

Comment: @AI. the answer has been update.